# Multiple Data Files Read in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have Data of different Stocks of various dates 
and each stock is stored in different Text Files (not in CSV)
How to Gather up Data in some way into a Single File

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like pandas and load each file to a data frame and then merge all of the data frames together, you can find some info here

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge all the text files into a single one, use a command `type`(if linux, use `cat`). Firstly, `cd` to the directory your text files in(for example: E:\data).

```
cd E:\data\ 
type *.txt > all.csv
```

and then you can use pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("all.csv")
...
```